# Passing a list to a TSQL 2008 Stored Procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

In MSSQL Server **2008** is there a way to construct the flowing as a stored procedure where the ... is passed in as a parameter. And **not** have to have a "separating" stored procedure or function which splits a csv and returns a table?

```
select *
from 
    atable
where 
    atable.id in (...)
```

Comment: Another good article :
[TSQL 2008- Table Valued Parameters](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/01/19/SQL-Server-2008-TSQL---Table-Valued-Parameters.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

Use a [table valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). [Here's how to use them from ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).