# C#/SQL get autoincremented field value

Tags: c#, .net, sql, auto-increment

I have a table with autoincremented primary key. In my code I am trying to receive the new autoincremented value when I execute each 'insert' query. Is there a way to do it programatically?

Thanks.

UPD:
Assume I have a table:
TABLE User ( userID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL , email VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL , UNIQUE ( userID ) );

And I when I insert new values (name and email) to this table I want automatically receive newly generated userID. Ideally I am looking for any ways to do that with a single transaction and without stored procedures.

Comment: Could you please show some example code of what you're currently doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your sql/stored proc return [scope_identity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) or if you are using Linq2SQL or EF the entity used for insertion gets the new id.

Answer (score 4):

In the stored proc it is:

```
ALTER    proc [dbo].[SaveBuild](
@ID int = 0 output,
@Name varchar(150)=null,
@StageID int,
@Status char(1)=null
)
as
 SET NOCOUNT ON


    Insert into Builds
    (name, StageID, status)
    values (@Name, @StageID, @Status)

    select @ID = scope_identity()

RETURN @ID
```

In the C# code you have:

```
public int SaveBuild(ref int id, ref string Name)
{

    SqlCommand cmd = GetNewCmd("dbo.SaveBuild");

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StageID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;

    ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
    id = (int)cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value;

    return id;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dependent upon your situation, you might be better off using [table-valued parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772777/sane-fast-method-to-pass-variable-parameter-lists-to-sqlserver2008-stored-procedu) to pass your inserts to a stored procedure, then use [OUTPUT INSERTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810962/getting-new-ids-after-a-bulk-insert-in-sql-server-2008) to return a table-valued parameter from your stored procedure.

It will drastically reduce the number of hits required if you're processing multiple items.

Comment: +1 for mentioning OUTPUT - no one seems to know about it and use it!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the SQL statement [`SELECT scope_identity()`](http://www.kamath.com/tutorials/tut007_identity.asp).

Comment: BAD BAD BAD - use scope_identity() for better (more accurate) results!

Answer (score 1):

Are you limited to building SQL on the client and sending it to the server?  Cause if you can use a stored procedure, this is easy to do.  In the stored proc, do the insert and then, either

1. Select Scope_Identity() as the last statement in the stored proc., or
2. Use a output parameter to the stored proc, (say named @NewPKValue)  and make the last statement:

   Set @NewPKValue = Scope_Identity()

Otherwise, you need to send a batch of commands to the server that include two statements, the insert, and Select Scope_Identity() and execute the batch as though it was a select statement