# how to pass multiple values using stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to pass multiple values using stored procedure ?

```
select * from Mytable where column1 in ('aa','bb','cc')
```

now i want to passed these column1 parameters using stored procedure

> how can i do that?

Comment: How about passing table variable as parameter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772777/sane-fast-method-to-pass-variable-parameter-lists-to-sqlserver2008-stored-proced?rq=1

Comment: select * from Mytable where Exec "Your Proc" in ('aa','bb','cc')

Comment: is the parameter list of comma separated id's (or strings)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Mytable
WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(Column1 AS varchar) + ',', @YourParameter)  > 0
```

Comment: Another note here: `@YourParameter` should start and end with `,` otherwise will miss the first and the last item from your list of comma separated values.