# Passing parameter to IN SQL statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I collected some values to be looked up from a DB column inside a string variable and was trying to pass this as a parameter in the SQL StoredProcedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InkDB]
(
@ser nvarchar(255),
@svt nvarchar(255)
)
AS
SELECT DISTINCT Details from tbData WHERE (Name IN @svt AND Address=@ser)
```

This gives me a `syntax error near @svt` message while trying to run the query.

From my webpage, the parameter has value something like `('PersonA', 'Person B', 'Person C')` that is being passed. How do I use the `IN` statement in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: Linked: http://stackoverflow.com/q/608562/55209

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a common mistake - you are passing a single value (expression) of type string to `IN` operator but `IN` expects a comma delimited list of values (expressions) and not a single string variable.

What you need to do here is to have a function that would split the given parameter into a multiple values based on given delimiter and then use that list with `IN` keyword. For example,

```
SELECT DISTINCT Details from tbData WHERE Name IN (SELECT Val FROM dbo.efn_Split(@svt, ',')) AND Address=@ser
```

where `efn_Split` is a table value function that will split comma-separated values into a table. See these various SO questions for implementation of such function:
[Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)
[How to split string using delimiter char using T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096630/how-to-split-string-using-delimiter-char-using-t-sql)

Yet another alternative is to construct the SQL statement and execute with `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with XML. Could not find this solution in the duplicate question so I add it here.

Your SP could look like this:

```
alter procedure InkDB
  @ser nvarchar(255),
  @svt xml
as

declare @T table
(
  Name nvarchar(50)
)

insert into @T
select T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(50)')
from @svt.nodes('/N') as T(N)

select distinct Details
from tbData 
where Name in (select Name from @T) and
      Address=@ser
```

And you would call it like this.

```
exec InkDB '', '<N>PersonA</N><N>PersonB</N>'
```

Comment: What does T.N.value means here ? Will you like to provide a link that contains it's details description ?

Comment: +1 This is reducing the code for comma separated values using "Table Valued Function".

Comment: @PankajGarg - `.nodes` and `.value` is used to parse and shred XML in SQL Server. You can read more about it here. [Introduction to XQuery in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> Dynamic Query

```
Alter procedure test
(
    @ser nvarchar(255),
    @svt nvarchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
   declare @sql nvarchar(Max)

   Set @sql='SELECT DISTINCT semester_code from mst_paper WHERE course_code IN ('+@svt+') AND branch_code='+@ser+''

   exec sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Comment: Wouldn't recommend this approach as it is likely to susceptible to SQL Injection (unless of-course calling code is ensuring the sanity of @svt parameter)!

Comment: No, This cannot cause SQL Injection. Reason being  - It's a stored proc with parameters. So definitely SQL parameters will be used from the language(c# or VB.Net). Right ?

Comment: @PankajGarg, if either `@svt` or @ser parameter is composed by concatenating user input then malicious user can inject any SQL in the query!

Comment: That is the case of inline SQL and not in parameterized query.

Comment: @PankajGarg - You are wrong. Since the SP uses the parameters to build and execute the query dynamically it **is** open for SQL Injection. If you use `'') select @@version --` as a parameter for `@svt` you will get a second result set with the version of SQL Server. You can of course do more devious stuff than that.

Answer (score -1):

`IN` needs to be as follows:

... IN (@param1, @param2, ...)

So, you should do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Details from tbData WHERE Name IN (@svt) AND Address=@ser
```

**Update:**

The alter procedure statement you provided in your question is syntactically incorrect. My answer provides the correct syntax for writing the statement and it compiles.

Reading your question over again, I see you have in fact have two issues. The first was a syntax error and the second passing in a comma delimited list in a single parameter.

The answer is you simply cannot provided a comma delimited list of values at runtime into a single string type parameter that is used in the `IN (...)` clause. Now, on this second point, I would argue that this is not a good design/programming approach to the problem, but it can be done using dynamic SQL or parsing out each value from the string parameter, store them into a temp table then revise your query to join to that, or use a (or use a table valued function and store the parsed items there, where it can be queried from.

Below is the corrected syntax for your code, but it would not solve the second aspect of passing in a string containing a comma delimited list of values. That could be solved as I described above.

For the syntax error, first, you can create a dummy table to test your code. Note, a typical database table should have a primary key. This is strictly a dummy table to test the statement:

CREATE TABLE TbData(
        Name nvarchar(255),
        Details nvarchar(255),
        Address nvarchar(255)
    );

Then, you can create the initial stored procedure:

CREATE PROCEDURE Test
    (
        @ser nvarchar(255),
        @svt nvarchar(255)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT Details FROM tbData WHERE Name IN (@ser) AND Address = @svt
    END

And finally, execute the alter stored procedure statement you had asked about:

ALTER PROCEDURE Test
    (
        @ser nvarchar(255),
        @svt nvarchar(255)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT Details FROM tbData WHERE Name IN (@ser) AND Address = @svt
    END

Comment: Chanding the query statement's where part to `WHERE (Name IN (@svt) AND Address=@ser)` gives me `Incorrect syntax near ')'` error.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. `@ser` contains a comma separated string of values like `PersonA,PersonB,PersonC` and OP wants the rows that matches any of the values. Your query will only return values where name is an exact match to the entire string.

Comment: Please do not down vote a answer that is syntactically correct and DOES fix the `Incorrect syntax` error. I have provided additional information which should lead you down the path of solving the second issue, of comma delimited values. I am not saying it is best practice, which is arguable.